# JavaScript Download downloading 1KB File

Tags: javascript, download

I have a javascript download functionality to download a LZ4  File and the path is dynamic. if i give the direct path in the browser url its downloading. But using javascript anchor tag link function its downloading 1 kb file only

```
    function download(filename, content) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                linkDownload(a, filename, content);
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click(); document.body.removeChild(a);
            }
var url = "file://test.com//Telemetry//RawDumps//ee359bcf-d280-4d7a-b35a-e74a160b083d.DMP.LZ4";
download(arun+ ".DMP.LZ4", url);
```

Comment: What a strange HTTP schema?Try to put "http://". As I know file:// is for local file system files, not files from internet.

Comment: i tried with http://test.com//Telemetry//RawDumps//ee359bcf-d280-4d7a-b35a-e74a160b083d.DMP.LZ4"; but still the same result @AlexNikulin

Comment: when a link is appeared at your page, clink on this link. Is file downloaded well? If a file is 1kb sized. Check file content, it can be server response with error or something